Redemption rdomail object query
I want to convert eml file to msg file for which i am using Redemption class.
Used the import method like this:
    RDOMail rdoMail = session.CreateMessageFromMsgFile(msgfilepath);
    rdoMail.Import(emlfilepath, (int)rdoSaveAsType.olRFC822)
    rdoMail.Save();
This converts the eml to msg but sometimes fails when there are large attachments (400mb+).
I tried to use different saveas types like olRFC822, olMsg, olMsgUnicode, olRFC822_Outlook, olRFC822_Redemption, but all tries to import full message.
Is there any way in Redemption where i can Import only the item without any attachments. I want that every time i use Import method, attachments are not included in the msg file. How can it be done.

What is the exact error raised by Import?

The behavior is not consistent. Sometimes, the large attachment gets skipped. The resultant msg file does not contain the attachment which was in the original eml. Sometimes, i receive out of memory error

Have you tried to use x64 Outlook and Redemption?

i need to use x32 Outlook as my application has dependency on that.

If you can share (OneDrive?) one of the problematic messages and send a link to redemption (at) dimastr (dot) com, I can try to take a look.
